# an entire DataTable object to byte then saved in database

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

im tasked to create a virtual database that clients can create from our web application and have them save data to.

the problem now is to have it stored for later re-use.

im thinking of dynamically creating a DataTable object in c# then convert it to byte[]. now i want to know if this would be practical to save on a database...

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WriteXml` to write to a stream:

```
byte[] raw;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    table.WriteXml(ms);
    raw = ms.ToArray();
}
...
raw = ...
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(raw)) {
    table.ReadXml(ms);
}
```

And write the `byte[]` to a `varbinary(max)` / `image` / etc column in a database if that is what you need (you mentioned database) - or just use xml.

If you are writing to a file, then just use a `FileStream` in place of a `MemoryStream`.